# Tensorflow - use same convolutional neural net on all inputs in a sequence

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Please suggest how to apply a convolutional neural network on all timesteps of an input sequence before feeding each timestep to a recurrent network in Tensorflow. 
One alternative is making a replica of the convolutional neural network for each time step and then use weight sharing among all the networks. Is there another way of doing this?